# Critical messages from gsm and gtk

Tags: fedora, logs, gtk, gsm

After upgrading to Fedora 18, I am seeing the following critical messages on `/var/log/messages` whenever I log on to the computer:

```
CRITICAL: gsm_manager_set_phase: assertion \`GSM_IS_MANAGER<br>
Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
```

Based on my limited knowledge, critical messages and above can affect the usage of my computer if I don't deal with these urgently. Not that they are affecting the current usage of my computer, but I would like to find out more about them (seems to deal with mobile technology and GIMP toolkit?) and how to turn them off if I do not need these services.

Comment: No, I don't think it matters, since it's happening when you close the program, am I wrong?

Comment: @warl0ck, both when shutdown and powering up. Why doesn't it matter? Care to explain?

Comment: Maybe start with how does it affect your usage?

Comment: Did you run with root user? if yes, please run with your user.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Gnome developers firmly hold the opinion that users never look at the error stream of GUI applications (it's hidden in some log file somewhere, or perhaps directly chucked into the bit bucket). They don't seem to ever look at the errors even when they're working on their programs. So you end up with a slew of “Gtk-CRITICAL”, “GObject-CRITICAL”, “GLib-Critical”, etc. “CRITICAL” messages from Gnome applications (and to a lesser extent from KDE applications) mean “the programmer has been careless, but hey, it seems to work, so who cares”.

By the way, GSM is the [Gnome Session Manager](https://live.gnome.org/SessionManagement/GnomeSession). Nothing to do with [cellular networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM).

Comment: I see, to make your answer complete, if it is not something important, can I turn it off? And how to do so?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow You can redirect the output to the bit bucket (`gnome-application >/dev/null 2>&1`) or to a log file (`gnome-application >>~/.gnome-debug-messages.log 2>&1`).